# What happens with static variables inside onDestroy method android?

Tags: android, static

I would like to ask why static variables aren't cleared after onDestroy() method gets called in android. Are static variables "safe" way to implement for example some int that will keep the state of an app and depending on the value for example something would happen or SharedPrefrences are the best in this kind of cases?

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are not controlled by the Android activity lifecycle in any way. They are part of the Java language and are designed to hold values across instances of a class.

That said, static variables are not the recommended way to store state information in an Android app.  Shared preferences are a better option, however these are stored to disk so they might be a little too persistent depending on your situation. If you just need to store Activity state across configuration changes or to restore an activity after being in the background for a long time, you can use the activity's save instance state.  See Activity.onSaveInstanceState() and Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(). To pass state data between activities, you could use intent extras. If you need to share variables between different app components, you could define variables in the application object. You could also use ViewModel. Really anything is preferable to static variables.